# How to change netbeans project explorer background in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, themes, netbeans-7

Im using netbeans 7.1 on ubuntu 11.10. I've installed a dark theme called "twilight".
But the project explorer is still white.

[Screenshot](http://s9.postimage.org/fo58qmhan/nbtheme.png)

How can i change the theme for the project explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should change your GTK theme to achieve this. Also, doing this will reflect to other applications you are using. Take a look here: http://gnome-look.org/index.php